# Issue with this.$el.find in Backbone framework

Tags: backbone.js

I get am "TypeError: this.$el is undefined" in my backbone View.

Here is my simple backbone view code

```
var tableViews = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("initialized");      
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.find(".clgcrt").removeClass("hidden");     
    }
});
```

I included "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js" url for my backbone.

Is there any problem with above backbone version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a very, very old version of Backbone. `this.$el` didn't get introduced until version 0.9.0.

You'll, at a minimum, need to use this version: http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.0/backbone-min.js.

Also, Justin in the comments mentioned you'll also need to use a recent version of Underscore.js, http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js. This needs to be included before you include Backbone.

Comment: Oh. I am getting "TypeError: f.isObject is not a function" when i change the above version. is there any issue with above js files file? What could be the problem?

Comment: You probably also need to update the underscore.js library. http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js

Comment: yes your correct. it is working after changed into new version of underscore and Jquery versions.